# Using two capturing groups with JavaScript's replace() function

Tags: javascript, regex, capturing-group

Given such a string `+as[23+"AS@D"-@]` replace all instances of `@` between the `[` and `]` with the number right after the `[` (in this case: `23`). Please answer using JavaScript (a suggestion is using `.replace()`). So using this algorithm, `+as[23+"AS@D"-@]` will be changed to `+as[23+"AS23D"-23]`

**Here is my regex `\[(\d+)[^\]]*(\@*)\]` The second capturing group is not captured ([Regexr](http://www.regexr.com/) tells me that nothing is captured within the second capturing group). I need help on making the second capturing group capture all instances of `@`**

I have tried using [Mozilla Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for help, but it did not work. Any help will be appreciated. Answers have to have explanation.

If this question is not clear enough, please tell me in the comments how can this be improved.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because stackoverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: @melpomene I have edited my question to show you my work.

Comment: Why do you think the second capturing group "is not captured"? (And what do you mean by that?)

Comment: @melpomene I think there is an error with my regex. If the regex works, then I would have solved my problem.

Comment: @melpomene http://www.regexr.com/ tells me that nothing is captured in the second capturing group.

Comment: The second capturing group captures a string of length zero (`[\@]*` (better written as `@*`) matches 0 or more `@` signs). It matches 0 times because there are no `@` signs following the number `[23`.

Comment: @melpomene My newest code doesn't work either: `\[(\d+)[^\]]*(\@*)\]`

Comment: In that version, `+"AS@D"-@` is matched by `[^\]]*`; `\@*` (better written as `@*`) has nothing left, so matches 0 characters. Then `\]` matches the final `]`.

Comment: @melpomene So how do I make it better?

Comment: Try doing it without a regex first.

Comment: Er. That's for you to figure out, isn't it? I mean, it's your homework.

Comment: `[^\]]*` matches your `@`

Comment: @vp_arth I want to capture `@` to replace it.

Comment: You should split it to 2 operations: 1. get a number, 2. replace all '@' to a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replace` with a callback function in Javascript:

```
var s = '+as[23+"AS@D"-@]';
var r = s.replace(/\[(\d+)[^\]]*\]/, function($0, $1) {
                   return $0.replace(/@/g, $1);});
//=> +as[23+"AS23D"-23]
```

`$0` represents whole string between `[` and `]` and `$1` is the first capture group i.e. number right after `[`.